# RxJS - FlatMap observer called multiple times

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to understand how **flatMap** works. I understand that it is a way for handling Observable< Observable < T>>.

Anyhow, I was testing the behaviour of it and got stuck with this:

```
let plusDom = document.querySelector('#plus');
let minusDom = document.querySelector('#minus');

let minusSource = Rx
              .Observable
              .fromEvent(minusDom, 'click');

let plusSource = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(plusDom, 'click');

plusSource
  .flatMap(function(c){
    console.log('Flatmap called');
    return minusSource;
  })
  .subscribe(function(e){
  console.log('done');
})
```

Here it is the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/sefoyowuqe/edit?html,js,console,output

I don't understand this behaviour:

```
3 clicks on plusDom prints:
Flatmap called
Flatmap called
Flatmap called
```

1 click on minusDom prints:

```
done
done
done
```

**Why when clicking the minusDom it replays the events as many times as we have click the plusDom?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flatMap` basically places the returned stream flat into the original stream. What you are probably looking for is `switchMap`, which will *switch* to that returned stream and *switch* to a new stream when the original source emits data by *discarding* the *old* one.

When in doubt, *switchMap* is usually the safest alternative to use.

See the marble-diagrams for comparison:

Flatmap doesn't *remove* previously "flattened" streams and :

[image: flatMap Marble Diagram]

Switchmap *removes* previously "switched" streams.

[image: switchMap Marble Diagram]